# On deselect doesn't works

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, react-native

I have the onSelectPhoto function which lets the user to select photos and stores them in an array to show them on the next screen when user clicks on "next? button. I have another function which is deselect ,which supposed to do the opposite and let the user to deselect/switch photos. The deselect function isnt working in this case.First of all its doesn't let me to choose photos which I already selected if deselect them .There is supposed to be option to select the same photo even if I deselected it.The other issue is that its doesnt let me to choose 5 photos as it is set in my supported length. What would be the right logic behind running through an array for the deselect?

onSelectedPhoto/onDeselectedPhoto:

```
onSelectPhoto = (photo, index) => {
        let photos = new Set([...this.selectedPhotos]);
        let len = this.selectedPhotosIndex;

        if (len > this.state.supportLength - 1) {
            this.limitDialog.open();
        }
        else if (len === (this.state.supportLength - 1)) {
            photos.add(photo);
            this.selectedPhotos = Array.from(photos);
            this.setState({selectedPhotos: this.selectedPhotos});
            this.props.setSelectedPhotos(len);
            this.selectedPhotosIndex = this.selectedPhotosIndex + 1;
        }
        else {
            this.selectedPhotosIndex = this.selectedPhotosIndex + 1;
            photos.add(photo);
            this.selectedPhotos = Array.from(photos);
        }
    }

    onDeselectPhoto = (photo, index) => {
        let photos = new Set([...this.selectedPhotos]);
        let len = this.selectedPhotosIndex;
        console.log('[...this.selectedPhotos]', [...this.selectedPhotos])

        photos.delete(photo);

        this.setState({selectedPhotos: Array.from(photos)});
        this.props.setSelectedPhotos(len);
        this.selectedPhotosIndex = this.selectedPhotosIndex - 1;
    }
```

My constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.selectedPhotos = [];
    this.selectedPhotosIndex = 0;

    this.state = {
        photos: null,
        loader: {
            loading: 0,
            message: "Loading photos..."
        },  
        selectedPhotos: [],
        supportLength: 5
    };

    this.props.navigation.setParams({notificationAction: this.onNotification, isIncome: this.props.isNewNotifications});
}
```

My Render:

```
<View style={{width: width, maxHeight: 600}}>
            <ScrollView >
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: width, flexWrap: 'wrap',marginBottom:40, justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                {
                    this.state.photos.map((p, i) => {
                        return (
                            <SelectedPhoto
                                key={i}
                                index={i}
                                style={{
                                    width: photoWidth,
                                    height: photoWidth,
                                }}
                                borderColor = "white" 
                                limit={this.state.supportLength}
                                photo={p}
                                onSelectPhoto={this.onSelectPhoto}
                                onDeselectPhoto={this.onDeselectPhoto}
                            />
                        );
                    })
                }
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={{ position:'absolute', right:-15, top:475 }}>
                <Button

                    onPress={this.onNext}  
                    containerViewStyle={{width: width}}
                    backgroundColor={Colors.red}
                    title='NEXT' />
            </View>             
        </View>
```

SelectedPhoto.js:

```
onPress = () => {
    console.log('onPress')
    if (this.state.selected === true) {
        this.setState({selected: !this.state.selected});
        this.props.onDeselectPhoto(this.props.photo);
    }
    else {
        console.log("this.props.selectedPhotos = ", this.props.selectedPhotos);
        console.log("this.props.limit = ", this.props.limit);

        if (this.props.selectedPhotos < this.props.limit - 1) {
            this.setState({selected: !this.state.selected});
        }

        this.props.onSelectPhoto(this.props.photo);             
    }
}
```